# Storing an array of strings and outputting the result to CSV

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, string

The below code writes a list of chocolate to a CSV file:

```
using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\chocListWRITE.csv", true)) //true:  append text to a file with StreamWriter. The file is not erased, but just reopened and new text is added to the end. 
{
    Chocolate _choc = new Chocolate();
    string line = _choc.Serialize();
    outfile.WriteLine(line);
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

in the console they are displayed as:

> 11111, Mars
>
> 22222, Bounty
>
> 33333, Snickes

But in the output CSV file they are displayed as:
11111, Mars 22222, Bounty 33333, Snickers

This is fine however **IF POSSIBLE** I would like the output file to store the results the same as the console, with a new line after each object. So for this I have tried to store them as an array and output that????

I am getting the error 'the file could not be written' index was outside the bounds of the array' with choc[arrayNo] = Escape(c._barcode.number);

```
//dummy data of list of chocolates assigned to 'Chocolates'
//serialize function
 string[] fullList = new string[] { };
        string[] choc = new string[] { };
        int arrayNo = -1;

        foreach (Choclate c in Choclates)
        {
            arrayNo = arrayNo + 1;
            choc[arrayNo] = Escape(c._barcode.number);//returns barcode as string
            choc[arrayNo + 1] = Escape(c._bar.barName);//returns name as string                             
        }

        return choc;
    }

    string Escape(String s)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        bool needQuotes = false;
        foreach (char c in s.ToArray())
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case '"': sb.Append("\\\""); needQuotes = true; break;
                case ' ': sb.Append(" "); needQuotes = true; break;
                case ',': sb.Append(","); needQuotes = true; break;
                case '\t': sb.Append("\\t"); needQuotes = true; break;
                case '\n': sb.Append("\\n"); needQuotes = true; break;
                default: sb.Append(c); break;
            }
        }
        if (needQuotes)
            return "\"" + sb.ToString() + "\"";
        else
            return sb.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: I think you need to initialise the size of `choc[]` like `string[] choc = new string[Choclates.Count];`

Comment: I use your code of `StreamWriter`. My file is printed with new string on new line.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: windows 8 64 bit...that surely doesnt matter?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are setting `arrayNo` to negative 1 you will still get an off by one error in the rest of your code.  MattC is correct, initialize the size of the array to be the same as the count of the `Choclates` list but then in addition, you need to change the line of code

```
choc[arrayNo + 1] = Escape(c._bar.barName);//returns name as string
```

Suppose you have an array that is 1 element then in your example, when you start inside the foreach loop, `arrayNo` is equal to 0:

```
var firstElement = choc[arrayNo] // arrayNo is 0 so an array of 1 item will be able to reference this
var secondElement = choc[arrayNo + 1] // choc is a 1 element array so you will get out of bounds exception
```

**EDIT**

Have you tried using "\r\n" instead of just "\n" for the newline character?  That makes a difference on some systems.

Comment: Your welcome, typically "thanks" is said on SO by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about using this?

```
return Choclates
  .Select(i => Escape(i._barcode.number) + "," + Escape(i._bar.barName))
  .ToArray();
```

This is a simple way to build a string array from a collection. You might have to add `System.Linq` to your usings.

Also, there's a few helpful methods you can use to make the whole job easier, for example, your `Encode` method can use this:

```
private static readonly char[] CharsToEncode = new []{'"', '\r', '\n', ',', '\t'};

string Escape(string str)
{
  if (str.IndexOfAny(CharsToEncode) != -1)
  {
    return "\"" + str.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
  }
  else
  {
    return str;
  }
}
```

In any case, building a string array is completely unnecessary when you're using a `StreamWriter`. You only have to go through each of the chocolates and `WriteLine` each of them as needed. This will also add the endlines. If your results are unexpected, you're doing something else wrong. Are you perhaps using the `WriteLine` method only once instead of once per chocolate? Or, is your output shown in the browser? In that case, it would tend to be interpreted as HTML, which means it would appear there are no line breaks (you have to use `<br />` for line breaks in HTML).

Comment: hey Luaan, thanks for the reply, no my OP displays the output as I see it. I will try the writeline in each to see if that helps. P.S thanks for refactoring my Escape function.